# Proving that limit does not exist

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

How can I prove that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n$ does not exist? Shall I do it by proving the sequence $\{n\}$ is not a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: How do you define the limit of a sequence?

Comment: Look at the formal definition of convergence for sequences. Negate this statement and prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sequence $\{x_n\}$, where $x_n=n$ is convergent, then it must be bounded.

Hence $\exists M (\gt0) \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $n=|n|\lt M$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Which contradicts the Archimedean property.

Hence $\{n\}$ is divergent and hence $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n$ does not exist.

${}$

---

> **Theorem:** *A convergent sequence of real numbers is bounded*.

${}$

> **Archimedean property of real number:** *The real number field is Archimedean i.e., if $a$ and $b$ be two any positive real numbers then there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $na\gt b$*.

Comment: I'd make the slight modification that $|n|<M$ if $n\color{red}{>N}$. We can have a sequence bounded as $n\to\infty$ but which is unbounded for $n<N$. Take $\frac1x$ for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Just suppose that the limit does exist, and it is $\omega$. Then, for any $n\geq N(\varepsilon)$, it should happen that $|n-\omega|<\varepsilon$, for any $\varepsilon>0$. But if $n\geq N(\varepsilon)$, so does $n+1$. Therefore, it must happen that both $|n-\omega|$ and $|n+1-\omega|$ are smaller than $\varepsilon$. Using triangle inequality, $1=|n-(n+1)|\leq |n-\omega|+|\omega-(n+1)|<2\varepsilon$. If $\varepsilon<1/2$, this is impossible. Therefore, the limit $\omega$ cannot exist.

Comment: what? I cannot get it what you have written after the 'using triangle inequality...'. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the definition of sequence convergence: Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence that converges to $a$. Then for $\epsilon > 0 $, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a-a_n|<\epsilon$ for $n \geq N $. This definition implies that if you pick any constraint $\epsilon > 0$, you're 100% guaranteed to find some stopping time $N$ such that the "tail" of $(a_n)$ after time $N$ has closer to the limit point $a$ than the constraint you picked. If you picked $\epsilon=1$, then for some $N$, $a_n$ is closer to $a$ for all $n \geq N$. You're guaranteed that $a_n$ won't suddenly *jump* out of that constraint distance you set.

I'm guessing you're comfortable with this definition(?), but I can explain further if you're a bit new to it.

Anyhow, let's say the sequence $(a_n)$ is divergent. Then any constraint $\epsilon>0$ you pick, $(a_n)$ will jump out of it. this is quite obvious for $(n)$, but less so for $(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k})$, which diverges to $\infty$.

So to prove a sequence is divergent, you simply have to find one constraint $\epsilon > 0$ such that $(a_n)$ will always eventually jump out of that distance $|a-a_n|<\epsilon$.

For the sake of contradiction, assume $(n)$ is convergent. Let $\epsilon = 1$. *(Note we can let $\epsilon$ be anything. This is true for the proof of the divergence of any diverging sequence)* Then there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|n-a|<\epsilon$ for any $n \geq N$. Since $|n-a|<\epsilon$, then $n < a + \epsilon$ for $n \geq \mathbb{N}$. Therefore $a + \epsilon$ is an upper bound of $\mathbb{N}$ since $a + \epsilon > n \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. This is a contradiction since $\mathbb{N}$ is not bounded. Therefore $(n)$ is not convergent, and so $(n)$ diverges. $\square$